# Using Filters to append a class to a template container

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis

Ok so I'm not very strong in php and java, I'm learning tho. Now I'm working with genesis using epik if that matters. Having no luck but trying to write a filter to add a class to a specific div on a template in functions.php

I've widened my site but I do not want the entire Blog section (blog home, categories and single post) to be as wide so I can use the native programming, plus learn how to write this stuff.

right now I'm controlling the width via my style sheet

```
    .page-id-89 .site-inner .wrap {
    padding: 0 5% 0;
}
```

How can I write this as a filter and hook it to the '.site-inner .wrap' in the above mentioned sections of the site?

so basically the function looks for '.site-inner .wrap' and appends a class (say .squeeze) with my padding to it on those post types

I appreciate any help as I learn my way through this! Have a great weekend

Answer (score 1):

The work is probably already done for you. If your theme is calling `body_class` correctly then your body element should already have classes set for the current template. For example, here is the body class of the home page of a WordPress site:

```
home page page-id-8 page-template
```

On the body class of a single post

```
single single-post postid-5418 single-format-standard
```

If you're using a custom page template, there will also be a class specific to that template, usually of the form `my-custom-template-php`

If all of the pages you wish to widen, or conversely the ones you do not wish to widen, have a particular body class you can use the class in your css selector. For example, this selector would only apply to the home page:

```
.home .site-inner .wrap
```

If you cannot distinguish the templates you wish to widen you can filter the `body_class` function and use conditional tags to add the desired class:

```
add_filter('body_class', function($classes) {
    if( is_home() ) {
        $classes[] = 'wide';
    }
    return $classes;
});
```

The above example will add the class `wide` to the body element on the home page.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I've used a body class and it did show up on the page source but it effects everything on the page. The Genesis blog template is simply blank and genesis(); and the loop it references is a core file i do not want to change. Id rather hook to it with a filter

Comment: `add_filter( 'genesis_attr_structural-wrap', 'custom_add_css_attr' );
function custom_add_css_attr( $attributes ) {
 if ( is_page_template( 'page_blog.php' ) ) {

  $attributes['class'] .= ' squeeze';
 }

 return $attributes;
}`

Comment: this works but adds the class to every wrap on the page. id like to target it to `.site-inner .wrap`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the helpful guides on hooks and filter in genesis bro.

http://genesistutorials.com/visual-hook-guide/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/genesis-visual-hook-guide/

https://alexanderdejong.com/genesis/changing-adding-custom-classes-html-5/

```
add_filter( 'genesis_attr_content-sidebar-wrap', 'custom_add_css_attr' );

function custom_add_css_attr( $attributes ) { 
    if ( is_page_template( 'page_blog.php' ) ) { 
        $attributes['class'] .= ' squeeze'; 
    } 
   return $attributes; 
}
```

You can use the `.site-inner .wrap .content-sidebar-wrap` instead of `.site-inner .wrap`. I think `.site-inner .wrap` is declared in general, so we can't add classes on the specific section.

Hope this will help.